# AWS CloudFormation ignore an existing resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure

I created a stack in CloudFormation and I need help to improve it.
In the stack below I have a VPC Endpoint but it is not possible to create it twice, that is, I cannot have two equal services name.
Does anyone have any idea to create a condition that if the VPC Endpoint is created it skips this step?

```
  VPCEndpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Join
        - ''
        - - com.amazonaws.
          - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
          - .execute-api
      PrivateDnsEnabled: true
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !Ref 9SecurityGroupId
      SubnetIds: 
        Ref: 8SubnetIds
      VpcEndpointType: Interface
      VpcId: 
        Ref: 7VpcId
  
  APIGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref 1Name
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - PRIVATE
        VpcEndpointIds:
          - !Ref VPCEndpoint
      Policy:
        Statement:
          - Action: 'execute-api:Invoke'
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: '*'
            Resource: 'execute-api:/*'
          - Action: 'execute-api:Invoke'
            Condition:
              StringNotEquals:
                'aws:SourceVpce': !Ref VPCEndpoint
            Effect: Deny
            Principal: '*'
            Resource: 'execute-api:/*'
        Version: 2012-10-17
```

Comment: If you created a stack from this template, and then have made changes to the template, why are you trying to create a new stack instead of updating the existing one? If you need a new stack for it, then you should tear down the existing one and deploy the new one. If you need to be able to create multiple versions of this stack, then you shouldn't put a common resource like a VPC endpoint in those stacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone have any idea to create a condition that if the VPC Endpoint is created it skips this step?

Yes, you have to either create [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) if you want the detection of pre-existing resources to be **fully automated**.

Otherwise, you can just create an **input parameter** to your template, e.g. `ShouldCreateTheInterfaceEndpoint`. Then you just set it to `false` or `true` when you deploy your template.

Comment: From what I understand the macros and the custom resource need a Lambda to check if the resource is existing or not and it doesn't work at the moment because this script will be in the AWS Service Catalog.

This parameter "ShouldCreateTheInterfaceEndpoint" I would put in the Parameters of my template?

Comment: @DanielFulgido Yes, it would be input parameter of your template.